# Wordpress "Site Can't Be Reached" Error, Cannot Access FTP or Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, http, server

I'm trying to access the Wordpress Admin Dashboard for this site: `https://www.disabilitylab.berkeley.edu/` and run into the "The site can't be reached" error. I have tried opening with other web browsers, clearing cache, and restarting computer, but this problem exists for other people, too. The site was fine a few hours ago, and only became like this after I successfully logged into the Wordpress dashboard and clicked to the Settings page. I have also tried pinging the IP address in Terminal (I'm on a Mac), and the feedback I receive is something like this:

```
PING 169.229.226.23 (169.229.226.23): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 169.229.226.23: icmp_seq=0 ttl=46 time=19.566 ms
64 bytes from 169.229.226.23: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=25.311 ms
64 bytes from 169.229.226.23: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=16.927 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
64 bytes from 169.229.226.23: icmp_seq=4 ttl=46 time=20.266 ms
64 bytes from 169.229.226.23: icmp_seq=5 ttl=46 time=28.095 ms
64 bytes from 169.229.226.23: icmp_seq=6 ttl=46 time=21.476 ms
64 bytes from 169.229.226.23: icmp_seq=7 ttl=46 time=18.824 ms
64 bytes from 169.229.226.23: icmp_seq=8 ttl=46 time=17.369 ms
64 bytes from 169.229.226.23: icmp_seq=9 ttl=46 time=17.519 ms
64 bytes from 169.229.226.23: icmp_seq=10 ttl=46 time=18.661 ms
64 bytes from 169.229.226.23: icmp_seq=11 ttl=46 time=21.928 ms
```

Articles online suggest working with plugins in Wordpress, but I cannot even access that because of this problem. There were also some advices about connecting with FTP, and I tried to connect using FileZilla, but it cannot connect to the server.

Also, before, when it was still possible to visit the site, this website actually could not appear on search engines for some reason. It's been up since April, and site indexing is turned on. I'm not sure if this is related to this problem.

Please let me know what I can do. Thank you!

Comment: Hi there, where is the website hosted on? On your school network? On cloud? On premise? It might have been some network issue, since you cannot even go to the page which suggest it is not really programming issue. If you have access to the server, try restarting it. Otherwise, contact your host and let them help you restart, see if that fix it. If it didn't fix is, there is not much we can do. What you experience is a very generic error, there is not much we can do about it unless we have access to your network, which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was the site does not support the subdomain www. in the url. The web hosting organization resetted the site and now it is able to reach, but only if one does not type www. at the beginning.